# "Invalid number of arguments, expected 0" in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, webstorm

I get this annoying warning in WebStorm, when I dispatch a function that uses the `createAsyncThunk`.

[image: [Warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY484.png)]

The login function looks like this:

```js
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/login',
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      return await authService.login(user)
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
        error.message ||
        error.toString()

      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    }
  }
)
```

I tried to search for this problem online and didn't find a solution. I wonder why is it complaining? The code seems to work fine.

Comment: Known issue with Jetbrains' IDEs: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53963/Dispatch-function-from-Reacts-useReducer-reports-wrong-argument-requirements

Answer (score 2):

When I replace the 'user' parameter with an object in the async function from the createAsyncThunk, the warning goes away and everything works as expected. Very strange. I wonder why is that?

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async ({name,password}, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    return await authService.login({name,password})
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()

    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
  }
})
```